What is the advantage of applying Tyvek HomeWrap or Huber Zip System on only one wall?
Unfortunately a window of my 1920ies California lath&plaster/stucco home was leaking, causing dry rot in the framing and requires to demo the stucco, redoing sheathing, tar paper, stucco and painting of one exterior wall.
My contractor will replace all wood where needed, put on new plywood sheathing, waterproofing paper and 3 scratches of stucco, followed by paint.
To my understanding, this does not provide a modern airtight seal and building envelope: The tarpaper is a water barrier but the wall does not get airtight.
Tyvek HomeWrap or Huber Zip System would provide an airtight building envelope (the former is not really compatible with Stucco walls in my understanding).
Now in normal conditions, the entire building envelope needs to be tight, i.e., all 4 walls.
Redoing my entire single exterior wall is a huge project and I really want to make this as perfect as possible. So I am considering using the Zip System before the stucco. This would only be one wall and clearly not provide the same efficacy as for all 4 walls.
However, how much benefit would it bring to use the Zip System on just one wall?
EDIT: I am going to split this into two separate questions: One about insulation, one about building envelope (this question).

Your contractor’s recommendation is typical and sound. (And probably a vast improvement over the rest of the house.)

For more money, you could upgrade the fiberglass to rockwool. Changing to an EIFS (Exterior Insulation and Finishing System) arrangement with sheet insulation protected by stucco would solve the thermal bridging at studs, but sounds like it might also mean finding a different contractor who does that, rather than the one you have who is (evidently)  unaware of it.

Insulation is one thing but the other is building tightness (in my understanding). EIFS might be overkill indeed (not as common in the Bay Area, twice the price and supposedly moisture issues). If I go with that contractor but rockwool, is there anything specific to be done about "building tightness"? Or would anything extra (EIFS) just benefit insulation?

I also slightly updated the question to emphasize on the "building tightness" aspect. How about spray foam insulation instead of rockwool?

I have split my question into 2 (insulation and envelope) to make it more targeted. The major question for the building envelope is whether there is any advantage using it on one wall only.

Whatever percentage of the air leaks that are from this wall will be reduced. Which is about all you would expect from doing one wall, but if the other walls are not in need of repair now, that would be normal.
When and if other walls need repairs they, too, can be upgraded, and if at some point all walls are upgraded, then not having thrown up your hands and said "but the rest of the building will still leak" on this wall (and done no sealing) pays off. In the interim, if the wall is, say, 25% of the wall area, 25% of the air  leaks are reduced.
